# Core i CPUs RAM DDR3

Tags: memory, intel-core-i5

please, I have read that Core i CPUs have built in memory controller. Oh, and I actually asked similiar question here, but this kind expands it, so therefore new question.

So, I have read that there are 1333MHz memory controllers in CPU. But, many Core i MB says they have support for eve 2000+ MHz, so how can CPU handle that? And, the same thing with voltages. I have read that for Core i CPU you need memory at 1.5 - 1.65 top, becouse of memory controller. But, first, there are many memories that rund from 1.7 to 1.9 and so on. So, they rae not compatible with Core i? And, is really too hard to give separate energy channel to RAM from logical ones? To have voltage RAM needs and to have logic levels CPU can survive? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. RAM is generally specified at 1.3GHz for i3/5/7 CPUs.
2. the ram works with a frequency multiplier as well, separate from the CPU multiplier. The ram will work at certain multiplies of the BCLK in that case. e.g. BCLK = 200, RAM multiplier = 8, CPU multipler = 20 will give you a modest overclock of ram at 1600MHz and CPU at 4GHz.
3. Use only ram specified at 1.65V for intel i3/5/7 or risk frying your CPU. higher voltage ram are for older and/or AMD platform only.

Comment: Good answer, but to put it explicitly because you didn't - *you can use higher speed RAM at the higher speed if you overclock*, hence so many boards supporting up to 2066.  (High speed RAM will just run at a lower speed if you don't.)